# Google Maps iOS SDK some map tiles loaded with green transparent color

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-styling

I am using the **Goolge Maps iOS SDK 2.1.1**. 
I manually had to integrate the framework since we are using Carthage and the Google Maps iOS SDK only supports Cocoapods.

I created a custom style with the [Google Maps Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) and loaded it as stated in the documentation.

When I zoom in some **map tiles get a weird green transparent color on certain zoom levels** (see picture). It's hard to see on the left screenshot so I marked the area that gets colored green on the right screenshot.

**Did anyone experience the same problem? What could be the cause for this?**

[image: Map tiles buggy green color]

**EDIT:**
I created a [sample project](https://github.com/harri121/GoogleMapsBug/tree/master/GoogleMapsBug). You have to set your Google Maps API key in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Can you provide a Github link to your project so we may debug it for you?

Comment: I added a link to the sample project to the description

Comment: I checked it on simulator and am not able to see the green color visible in your screenshots. Can you please provide specific location where this appears, if reproducible? Would be great if you can provide lat long and zoom level.

Comment: pan to europe and try to zoom in and out. It's not happening on all zoom levels. It mostly happens when new text is rendered or the map is getting more detailed terrain.

Answer (score 2):

I think it just may have to do with the style for this, I have never experienced anything like this. Or maybe it has to do with the **device** itself.

Comment: I tried it with the Simulator, on Devices and I also tried to use different styles. In every situation I get the same bug.